# UINavigationController: Release ViewController's memory when popped

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller

I have seen a few posts on this subject here on SO, but no definitive answers.  Here is my problem.

I have a `UINavigationController` which I use as a gallery.  On the first controller I load up a bunch of remote images.  This increases my memory size, but not by that much.  When clicking an image, it will push on another `viewController` which has images for the gallery just clicked.  This might load in another 1MB or more of data from those images.

The problem here is that a user might browse any number of these galleries.  Since when I pop the viewController, that memory is not released I start to get too much memory usage in my app when the users continues to browse the galleries.

Is there any way that I can release this memory when I pop my `viewController`?  Perhaps in my `viewDidDisappear:` method? If so, what would I release?  And how can I create it again?  I tried this to a point, such as releasing my view, but I get crashes.

Any insight into this issue?

```
PhotosGalleryiPad *gallery = [[PhotosGalleryiPad alloc] init];
gallery.items = self.items;
gallery.asset = self.currentAsset;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:gallery animated:YES];
[gallery release];
```

Comment: Honestly...it sounds like the memory really should be unloading in "dealloc" of the view you have loaded when you pop it off the stack. Are you sure you are releasing all the photograph data in dealloc properly? Unless you are somehow allowing the user to navigate forward through a bunch of views endlessly without ever click the "Back" button...views in the view navigator should dealloc on a click of the back button in the header generally. If that is the case then you might want to look at a different navigation paradigm.

Comment: No, dealloc is getting called and my properties are being released.  They just click, push the controller, then click the normal "back" button to pop back to the root.

Answer (score 0):

If you are "popping" views onto the foreground like this:

```
infoScreen = [[[infoScreen alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoScreen" bundle:nil] autorelease];
infoScreen.view.center = CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width / 2, self.view.bounds.size.height / 2);
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.view];
```

Then you would do `[infoScreen release];`
to release/free the view from memory.
Remember anything you `alloc`, or `retain` (there are other situations too but i forget them off hand) you need to `release`.

Comment: I understand memory management rules.  I am not sure I am following your suggestion here.

Comment: maybe i misunderstood your question, i thought u needed help releasing the memory from viewcontrollers that arent being used any more.

Comment: I do, it seems that it holds onto the memory when I pop the view controller back off the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You normally release any memory in the `dealloc` method of the view controller that gets popped off the stack.

However, if you're talking about images and you loaded them with `[UIImage imageNamed:]` then UIKit may be caching them. Try faking a memory warning in the simulator (from the Hardware menu) and see if that unloads these cached images.

You can also do a heapshot analysis in Instruments. Mark the heap before loading the view controller, mark it again after closing the view controller, and see which objects stick around.

Answer (score 0):

Where, exactly, are you retaining these gallery images?

Let me take a guess that `gallery.items` is a mutable collection (possibly an array) holding the images.  As the user visits new galleries, more images are added to this array.  From view controller to view controller, you are passing a pointer to this array:

```
gallery.items = self.items;
```

So, when you pop the view controller, you are still left with the same, enlarged, array.  The issue, then, is how to cull this array of the newly added images when you pop a view controller.

Rather than passing a pointer, you could make a [shallow copy of the collection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Copying.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010162-SW1).  If it's a mutable array, you could do as follows:

```
gallery.items = [self.items mutableCopyWithZone:nil];
```

Then, when a view controller is popped, its `items` array is released.  The objects added by the popped view controller are released, but the old objects are still retained in the previous view controller's `items` array.

(I'm just taking a guess.  If I'm wrong, it would be helpful if you explained where you're retaining these images.)

Comment: No, it isn't an array of images.  It is an array of image URLs, just NSStrings. I need to do some research, I have a feeling this might be caused by some third party code I am using.

Comment: It doesn't sound like it's the view controller that's retaining the images.  If you're releasing properties appropriately in the dealloc, the only way I can think of that a view controller would retain anything is thru a collection that isn't being copied.  Maybe if you look at where the images are created or downloaded, you'll find what is holding on to them.